# How do I redirect warnings in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I am trying to redirect warnings in a shell script. I know to redirect I have to do

```
command 2>/dev/null
```

But what I am redirecting is the warning from an if statement. Something like:

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ] 2>/dev/null
```

But when I do that my output also goes into null. I mean, if the condition is true then normally I enter into the if-block and a warning msg get displayed "integer expression expected" and all works fine. But when I add the redirection, it just doesnt work. My guess is output is also being redirected. How do I make this work?

Comment: It's not redirecting your output. If the `test` itself is generating an error, the condition does not succeed, and the "true" part of the `if` statement does not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ] 2>/dev/null
```

say:

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b"  2>/dev/null ]
```

i.e. include the redirection within the `test`.

---

It's better to make use of the mathematical form instead:

```
(( a > b )) && echo "a is greater than b"
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. Input redirections are processed before the `test` command is run, and when invoked as `[`, `]` is just another argument. You could write `[ "$a" 2>/dev/null -gt "$b" ]` with the same result: the `2>/dev/null` is removed before `[` sees its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

To suppress error generated by condition you can do:

```
[ "$a" -gt "$b" ] 2>/dev/null
```

However I strongly suggest you find better ways to make sure your *variable are of correct type* before entering into this condition.

#### UPDATE

As per comment here is simplistic `version comparison` script:

```
v1="$a"
v2="$b"
first=$(echo -e "$v1\n$v2" | sort -nr | head -1)
[[ "$first" = "$v1" ]] && echo "$v1 greater than $v2" || echo "$v1 same or smaller than $v2"
```

Comment: Actually you are right, I am not comparing integers, but still everything is working fine and I have no clue why!

Comment: That's why it not a good idea to suppress error in condition like this. If you provide more details I can suggest better ways.

Comment: Sure, it's the same thing, I am actually comparing versions, something like 1.4.4 and 1.7.2 and I need to find the bigger one. I tried with -gt and for God knows what reason it's working. Do you have any better approach?